# Rails - open page from URL for respond_to js

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have link_to with remote=>true .Everything is ok - when I click on link, controller:

```
def show
   respond_to |format|
     format.js
   end
end
```

just open page in JS format:

```
$.fancybox('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "items/show")) %>',{}
```

And question. How can I open that page when user just put URL in browser. Is it possible? Right now when i put URL I only see :

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

what is "right" because there is no ask for JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to open your page in browser via URL, by default, you have html request. But your controller is responsible only for processing javascript (js) requests. so, I would add ability to process html requests as well (via `format.html`) and render show.html.erb(haml, slim) whatever through it. Just usual RoR case.

Comment: hm... so solution is to put html respond and for example set trigger  for link_to in that html = then I will have "auto" opened fancybox ... ok I will try this.